# Integral of partial derivative equaling zero in proof of the divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, partial-derivative

In the proof I am following of the divergence theorem, we define an integrable function $F : U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which has compact support in some open and bounded subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. We need to show $\int_U \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}\lambda^n = 0$ for $1 \le j \le n$. I came up with the following solution, but somehow it doesn't make sense intuitively.
My solution:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}\lambda^n = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}u_j \;\textrm{d}\lambda^{n-1}
$$

Furthermore
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}u_j = \lim_{b \rightarrow\infty} \lim_{a \rightarrow\infty}(F(u_1,\dots, b,\dots,u_n)- F(u_1,\dots, a,\dots,u_n)) = 0 - 0 = 0
$$
since $U$ is bounded. Since $\text{supp} (\partial_jF) \subseteq \text{supp} (F) \subseteq U$, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}\lambda^n = \int_{U} \partial_jF(u) \textrm{d}\lambda^n = 0
$$

However, even after having proven it (hopefully correctly) I still feel like I should be able to come up with a counter-example. Can anybody provide some intuition?

Comment: Does the fundmental theorem of calculus make intuitive sense to you?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, after thinking about it for a bit, I figured it out.